# Excel if index match 2 criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match

Yesterday I was challenged with a 1-criteria query, today a 2-criteria query has me equally baffled, despite yesterdays lesson. Here is the new nested, if-index-match formula:

```
{=IFERROR(IF(INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1,(B2=$AO$2:$AO$31)*("Good"=$AT$2:$AT$31),0))="PG",3,IF(INDEX($C:$C,ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(B2=$AO$2:$AO$31)*("Bad"=$AT$2:$AT$31),0)))="PG",-5)),"NaN")}
```

The result I get is "3" when the input is "Good"; the result I get is "NaN" when the input is "Bad". I want the formula to result in "-5" when "Bad" is input, but error-checking has an #N/A in there somewhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is too complex and there are too much unknown ranges so I don't really want to investigate what exactly should happen under what circumstances. But if you compare the 'good' and the 'bad' (and the ugly??) conditions you can see a discrepancy:

Good

```
IF(INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1,(B2=$AO$2:$AO$31)*("Good"=$AT$2:$AT$31),0))="PG"
```

Bad

```
IF(INDEX($C:$C,ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(B2=$AO$2:$AO$31)*("Bad"=$AT$2:$AT$31),0)))="PG"
```

I guess there is at least one source of your problem

Comment: I've found a preferable way to do this with _countif(s)_, but the desired result should be similar to an AND join, where each condition must be met. Here's the latest: `=IF((COUNTIF($AO$2:$AO$31,B14)*COUNTIF($AT$2:$AT$31,"Good")*COUNTIF(C14,"PG")),3,IF((COUNTIF($AO$2:$AO$31,B14)*COUNTIF($AT$2:$AT$31,"Bad")*COUNTIF(C14,"PG")),-5))` ..it would be easier if all the ranges were contiguous..